# How to use BeautifulSoup and lxml together?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm very new in Python. How to use BeautifulSoup and lxml together?

It is recommended to use lxml as parser in [beautifulsoup website](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

```
def get_html():

        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import lxml

        soup = BeautifulSoup(open("http://www.google.com"));
        #print(soup.prettify());
        print(soup.title);

if __name__ == '__main__':
        get_html()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the parser when you call the `BeautifulSoup()` constructor:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read(), "lxml")
```

Comment: line 6, in get_feeds
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("http://www.google.com"),"lxml");
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://www.google.com'

Comment: @Sop: I assumed you had your url loading set up already. Use something like `requests` or `urllib2` to load pages for parsing. Updated to use `urllib2` to load the page.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new in Python. Why can't we use lxml directly open remote page?

Comment: @Sop: Yes, `lxml` supports loading a remote URL, but *BeautifulSoup* does not. Since you want to use the BeautifulSoup API, you'll have to do your own URL loading.